# How to use the GWT EventBus

Tags: java, events, gwt, event-handling

I wonder how to use the `EventBus` or whether there are some better solutions to send an `Event` through the project.

`Widget1` has a `Button`. `Widget2` has a `Label`, that should change when I press the button. These widgets are in a `DockLayout`:

```
RootLayoutPanel rootLayoutPanel = RootLayoutPanel.get();
DockLayoutPanel dock = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);

dock.addWest(new Widget1(), 10);
dock.add(new Widget2());

rootLayoutPanel.add(dock);
```

I have declared an `handleClickAlert` in `Widget1`:

```
@UiHandler("button")
void handleClickAlert(ClickEvent e) {
    //fireEvent(e); 
}
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

When you divide the project into logical parts (for example with MVP), then the different parts sometimes need to communicate. Typical this communication is done by sending status changes, e.g.:

- user logged-in / logged-out.
- user navigated directly via URL to a page, so the menu needs to be updated.

Using the event bus is quite logical in those cases.

To use it you instantiate one `EventBus` per app which is then used by all other classes. To achieve this use a static field, factory or dependency injection (GIN in case of GWT).

Example with your own event types:

```
public class AppUtils{

    public static EventBus EVENT_BUS = GWT.create(SimpleEventBus.class);
}
```

Normally you'd also create your own event types and handlers:

```
public class AuthenticationEvent extends GwtEvent<AuthenticationEventHandler> {

public static Type<AuthenticationEventHandler> TYPE = new Type<AuthenticationEventHandler>();

  @Override
public Type<AuthenticationEventHandler> getAssociatedType() {
    return TYPE;
}

@Override
protected void dispatch(AuthenticationEventHandler handler) {
    handler.onAuthenticationChanged(this);
}
}
```

and the handler:

```
public interface AuthenticationEventHandler extends EventHandler {
    void onAuthenticationChanged(AuthenticationEvent authenticationEvent);
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.addHandler(AuthenticationEvent.TYPE, new AuthenticationEventHandler()     {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationChanged(AuthenticationEvent authenticationEvent) {
            // authentication changed - do something
        }
    });
```

and fire the event:

```
AppUtils.EVENT_BUS.fireEvent(new AuthenticationEvent());
```

Comment: When firing the event, how could I send an object? In my case I would need to send an class that contains my users information.

Comment: You can have a field in your custom event and set it via constructor, i.e. 'new AuthenticationEvent(someObject)'

Comment: Protip: use [gwteventbinder](https://github.com/google/gwteventbinder) to minimize the code needed to define a new event. For the AuthenticationEvent above, your event would *just* have to extend `GenericEvent`.

Comment: Better to use 'ResettableEventBus' not to have a global event bus which won't be killed after the lifecycle of 'Presenter' and might result multiple identical event handlers for one event.