# Using UiBinder to create a login panel. How to make a user loggin and show other widgets

Tags: java, gwt

I created a a widget has a log in panel:
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:style>
        /* Add CSS here. See the GWT docs on UI Binder for more details */
    </ui:style>
        <g:VerticalPanel width="200px" height="auto">
            <g:Label text="Username:" width="100%" height="auto" />
            <g:TextBox ui:field="Username" width="100%" height="auto" />
            <g:Label text="Password:" width="100%" height="auto"/>
            <g:PasswordTextBox ui:field="Password" width="100%" height="auto" />
            <g:Cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_RIGHT">
                <g:Button text="Login" ui:field="button" height="25px"/>
            </g:Cell>
        </g:VerticalPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And here is the generated class:
public class LoginPanel extends Composite implements HasText {

```
    private static LoginPanelUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(LoginPanelUiBinder.class);

    interface LoginPanelUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, LoginPanel> {
    }

    public LoginPanel() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @UiField
    Button button;

    @UiField
    TextBox Username;

    @UiField
    PasswordTextBox Password;

    public LoginPanel(String firstName) {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @UiHandler("button")
    void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
        Window.alert("Hello!");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username.getText();
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

I want to access the click event of this class on the onModuleLoad so that I can know when the user has clicked the button and has successfully logged in, so I can call other panels I created. Only thing this does is an alert.

This is the first time I'm playing with UiBinder, so I might be missing something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want your `LoginPanel` to notify your main app class when a user has logged in?

This is really a job for [`EventBus`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html). Take a look at the exact use case that you need (AuthenticatedEvent): [How to use the GWT EventBus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030202/how-to-use-the-gwt-eventbus/6030379#6030379)

Answer (score 2):

First thing you would need to do is to send user-name password to the server. You can use RPC for this purpose. Then in your RPC callback ( `onsuccess` ) you can show the rest of your UI.
Here is a skeleton of what you will need to do:

```
    private AsyncCallback loginCallback = new AsyncCallback(){
      public void onSuccess(){
            // show ui here
      }
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
         Window.alert("debug: login failed, message from server: " + caught.getMessage());
      }
    }
    @UiHandler("button")
    void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
        Window.alert("debug: Sending login data to server");
        LoginServiceAsync loginAsync = ... 
        loginAsync.doLogin(getUsername(),getPasword(),loginCallback);
    }
```

You will need to create a LoginService RPC service using GWT's RPC facilities.